# preventDefault() stopping jquery form values being submitted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have been trying to create an invitation only system for a wordpress site I'm working on (trying to avoid plugins where possible).

The site is a world of warcraft guild website and I have a page listing new applicants to the guild, with Accept and Reject options. That is all working fine.

However, I'm trying to do the form submission via ajax and that is where I'm getting confused.
I have my form

```
<?php
    global $current_user;
    // if the user can send invites
    if (current_user_can("invite_users")) {
    ?>
    <form action="applicantaccept" class="applicantacceptform" method="GET">
        <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $row['Email'];?>"  />
        <input type="hidden" name="invitecode" value="<?php echo generateRandomString(); ?>" />
        <input style="background: none; border: none; color: white; text-decoration: underline; font-size: 1em; float: left;" type="submit" value="Send Invitation" />
    </form>
    <?php
    }
?>
```

And I have my jquery:

```
// ACCEPT
$('.applicantacceptform').submit(function (ev) {
    // INVITE FORM
    var form = $(this);

    var email = form.find('input[name="email"]').val();
    var invitecode = form.find('input[name="invitecode"]').val();

    $.post("applicantaccept", {
        email: "" + email + "",
        invitecode: "" + invitecode + ""
    })
        .done(function (data) {
        alert("Applicant Accepted" + data);
    })
        .fail(function (data) {
        alert("Failed To Accept Applicant. Please speak to administrator if this problem continues");
    });
ev.preventDefault();
});
```

When I submit with the `ev.preventDefault()` present, the alert shows success. however the values are parsed as empty strings through to the target page giving me blank sql records.  However, if I remove the preventdefault, I'm ofcourse following the link, but the values are now sent through correctly.

What could be causing this?

---

Solved: Thanks to @Pointy for the fix, working code below (simply switched "GET" in the form to "POST"

```
   <?php
global $current_user;
// if the user can send invites
if (current_user_can("invite_users")) {
    ?>
    <form action="applicantaccept" class="applicantacceptform" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $row['Email'];?>"  />
        <input type="hidden" name="invitecode" value="<?php echo generateRandomString(); ?>" />
        <input style="background: none; border: none; color: white; text-decoration: underline; font-size: 1em; float: left;" type="submit" value="Send Invitation" />
    </form>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Looks to me as if the call to `ev.preventDefault()` is **outside** the event handler code.

Comment: thank you karthikr, now the problem is obvious... `ev` can't be used outside of the function

Comment: Also, that `"" + email + ""` stuff is not necessary, as the return value from `.val()` will always be a string.

Comment: @Pointy (or `undefined`)

Comment: Your form has `method="GET"` but in your JavaScript you're using POST. @Ian well yes, but only (I think) if there's no element matching the selector.  The point is that if you're actually getting the value of an element, it'll be a string.  (Actually even that may be wrong; the explicit "casting" is still not necessary since jQuery will stringify the parameters anyway.)

Comment: AH sorry guys that was my mistake, I actually typed that in when creating this post as copied a version without. the preventdefault is normally inside (or one line up) will edit the post now to correct! sorry for confusion!  thanks for the tip with the "" + stuff :)

Comment: @Pointy I think I could hug you! I hadnt even noticed the GET POST mixup! teaches me to write code when I'm needing sleep haha! Its all fixed now, will edit post to clarify the fix

Comment: @Pointy Oh I know, I was just referring to your `will always be a string` part :) And you're right, it's `undefined` only if there's no matched elements

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `return false;` instead of `ev.preventDefault();`?

Comment: Is this question or an answer? or both?

Comment: I gave it a go, got the exact same result :/

Comment: I can't comment yet, so it's both :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the `ev.preventDefault()` as the first line in that function. My guess is it's trying to follow the link before firing the form submit.